# Bounding the second derivative of the log-determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to use the log-determinant to regularize an optimization problem. To make the argument work, I need to bound the second derivative of the log-determinant.

I need to prove that $\text{Tr}\left( \left(A^{-1} B\right)^2\right) \geq 1$ whenever:

1. $A$ is positive semidefinite
2. $B$ is symmetric, has zeroes on the diagonal, and has at least one entry which is $\geq 1$.
3. The diagonal entries of $A$ are 1.

From messing around a bit it seems like in fact there are always unit vectors $v, w$ such that $v^T A^{-1} B w \geq 1$---for example, this is true if B has only a single large entry, or if A and B commute. That would imply the conclusion and seems like it should be easy enough to confirm or deny, but I'm stumped.

Any thoughts?

Comment: By "positive" you mean "positive definite"?

Comment: A is not assumed to be symmetric, is  it?

Comment: A is positive, thus symmetric.
The problem is invariant under the $GL(n)$-action 
$X\mapsto g^T.X g$ for $g\in GL(n)$. Any $g$ is of the form $g=n.a.k$ where $n$ is lower triangular with 1's on the diagonal, $a$ is diagonal with positive entries, and $k$ is orthogonal (Gram-Schmidt or Iwasawa). Choose $a=I$ so to not mess up too much your assumptions.
There is an $n$ such that $n^T.A.n$ is diagonal with positive entries.
Compute this entries. Check $n^t.B.n$.
I hope this helps.

Comment: About the entry of $B$ larger than $1$, is it diagonal ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, A is positive semidefinite (and symmetric). 

The large entry of B is not necessarily on the diagonal.

Also, note that the claim is easy by rote computation if B has only one large entry. This is the observation that inspired me to try to prove this bound (that, and hope).

Peter: I don't see how to use the large entry of B after making such a transformation. Does this translate into some nice property of $n^T B n$ or $g^T B g$?

Comment: $A$ is positive definite (since invertible). Viewing $A$ as an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$, your formula describes the natural induced inner product on the space of symmetric bilinear forms. This is the background for my description of the natural invariance group above.

Comment: Does it help at all that—from the cyclicity of trace and the fact that A is positive definite, the LHS can be written as $\Tr[(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^2]$? (where $A^{-1/2}$ is the unique positive definite matrix square root of $A^{-1}$) Clearly $M\equiv A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$ is symmetric. Then the LHS is $Tr(M^2)$ which is just the square of the Frobenius norm of M. Then the question is: what are the singular values of $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Nice question! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an argument based on convex optimization.

Consider the case where $B$ has a one on the diagonal and the rest of the matrix is arbitrary. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $b_{11}=1$. Thus, we can write the general matrix $B=E+C$, where $E=e_1e_1^T$ with $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ being the first canonical basis vector, and $C$ is a symmetric matrix with $C_{11}=0$.

(*Note:* If the entry $\ge 1$ is an off-diagonal, then we can write $B=e_ie_j^T+e_je_i^T$, and run an argument similar to the one below---this one is somewhat more tedious so I did not work it out).

To save on typing, first define the notation:
$\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}$

\begin{equation*}
  Z = A^{-1},\quad M = Z \otimes Z,\quad e=\vect(E)\quad c=\vect(C).
\end{equation*}

Then, the trace under question is:
\begin{equation*}
  \mbox{trace}(Z(E+C)Z(E+C)) = e^TMe + c^TMc + 2c^TMe.
\end{equation*}
Actually, we have $(Kc)^TMc$ as the second term, where $K$ is the [*commutation matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix), but after some simplifications, it will turn out that we can drop $K$.

Now, we minimize $c^TMc + 2c^TMe$ subject to $c^Te=0$ (and the constraint that $Kc=c$ to ensure symmetry, but this constraint can be eliminated, so I've dropped it).

Introduce the Lagrange multiplier $\nu$ corresponding to the constraint $c^Te=0$, the 
first-order optimality conditions for this *convex optimization* problem are:
\begin{equation*}
  2Mc + 2Me - \nu e = 0,\qquad c^Te=0.
\end{equation*}

Thus, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  Mc &=& (\nu/2) e - Me\\\\
  c  &=& (\nu/2) M^{-1}e - e\\\\
  &\implies& c^Te = (\nu/2) e^TM^{-1}e - e^Te\\\\
  &\implies& \nu=2\qquad\text{since}\ e^TM^{-1}e=1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, in particular, an optimum $c$ must satisfy
\begin{equation*}
  c = M^{-1}e - e,
\end{equation*}
from which it follows that $e^TMc =  1 - e^TMe$ and $c^TMc=0-c^TMe$. Thus, the objective is
\begin{equation*}
  c^TMc + 2c^TMe= c^TMe = 1 - e^TMe,
\end{equation*}
from it immediately follows that
\begin{equation*}
  \mbox{trace}(Z(E+C)Z(E+C)) = e^TMe + c^TMc + 2c^TMe \ge 1.
\end{equation*}