# Are gaussians with different moments far in total variation distance?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

If two Gaussians disagree on one moment, it seems like this should imply that they have a large variation distance--equivalently, if two Gaussians are close in variation distance it's hard for their moments to differ very much. But I'm having trouble proving this without getting into a terrible mess and ending up with weak bounds. I'm hoping someone here can offer a slick proof or point me to one.

Suppose that $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are two positive-semidefinite matrices, with diagonal entries bounded by 1, and that $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ differ by at least $\delta$ in one of their entries.

Can we lower-bound the total variation distance between the multivariate gaussians with covariance matrices $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$? In particular, is this distance at least $\Theta(\delta)$? It seems like it ought to be, since the gaussians are pretty well concentrated. But trying to formalize the obvious approach seems to create a bit of a mess.

Edit: Douglas Zare and guest point out that you can trivially reduce to the 2 dimensional case by projecting onto the relevant subspace. So we can restrict attention to that case.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No; together with the strong concavity of the entropy it might give an alternative and conceptually clearer proof of [this claim](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125511/bounding-the-second-derivative-of-the-log-determinant), in which I am once again interested. What suggests this might be a homework problem?

Comment: for the lazy amongst us, could you write out a formula (after simplifying the stuff that is unimportant for the bound) for this TV distance?

Comment: If the entry is on the diagonal, projecting to this coordinate gives $1$-dimensional Gaussians (where you can compute the total variation distance explicitly). If the entry is off the diagonal, projecting to the two coordinates involved reduces this to a problem on $2$-dimensional Gaussians.

Comment: Suvrit: it's a big integral, of the absolute value of the difference between the Gaussian densities. I don't really see how to simplify it usefully, and writing it out is a mess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Letting $\mu_{a,\Sigma}$ be the Gaussian measure with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and mean $a$. Then (double) the variation distance can be written as
$$
\left\lVert\mu_{a_1,\Sigma_1}-\mu_{a_2,\Sigma_2}\right\rVert_1 = \max_f\left\lvert\mu_{a_1,\Sigma_1}(f)-\mu_{a_2,\Sigma_2}(f)\right\rvert,
$$
where the maximum is taken over functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert f\rvert\le1$. Taking $f(x)=\exp(ix\cdot u)$ for a fixed $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$, plugging in the characteristic function for Gaussian distributions,
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lVert\mu_{a_1,\Sigma_1}-\mu_{a_2,\Sigma_2}\right\rVert_1&\ge\max_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left\lvert e^{ia_1\cdot u-\frac12 u^t\Sigma_1u}-e^{ia_2\cdot u-\frac12 u^t\Sigma_2u}\right\rvert\\
&\ge\max_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left\lvert e^{-\frac12 u^t\Sigma_1u}-e^{-\frac12 u^t\Sigma_2u}\right\rvert\\
&=\max_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n,\lVert u\rVert_1=1}\max_{\lambda\ge0}\left\lvert e^{-\frac12 \lambda^2u^t\Sigma_1u}-e^{-\frac12 \lambda^2u^t\Sigma_2u}\right\rvert.
\end{align}
$$
Note that, for any $1\ge\alpha > \beta > 0$, we can consider $\lambda=1/\sqrt{\alpha}$ to get the following bound,
$$
\max_{\lambda\ge0}\left(e^{-\lambda^2\beta}-e^{-\lambda^2\alpha}\right)\ge e^{-\frac\beta\alpha}-e^{-1}=\Theta\left(1-\frac\beta\alpha\right)=\Theta(\alpha-\beta).
$$
Hence, as we are assuming $\Sigma_i$ are positive semidefinite with diagonal entries bounded by 1, we have $1\ge u^t\Sigma_iu\ge0$ for $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert u\rVert_1=1$ and,
$$
\left\lVert\mu_{a_1,\Sigma_1}-\mu_{a_2,\Sigma_2}\right\rVert_1=\Theta\left(\max_{\lVert u\rVert_1=1}\left\lvert u^t(\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2)u\right\rvert\right)
$$
For any symmetric matrix $M$ we have $2M_{ij}=(e_i+e_j)^tM(e_i+e_j)-e_i^tMe_i-e_j^tMe_j$ where $e_i$ is the unit vector along coordinate dimension $i$, from which we get
$$
\left\lVert\mu_{a_1,\Sigma_1}-\mu_{a_2,\Sigma_2}\right\rVert_1=\Theta\left(\lVert\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2\rVert_\infty\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this the bounty unless a significantly cleaner solution crops up (unless there is some etiquette about this I don't know).

Minor (I think) issue: the covariance matrices can have eigenvalues more than 1. But you only need to apply this bound for sparse vectors, so it looks like you are good.

Comment: I switched the norm used for $u$ to fix the minor issue

Comment: Can you explain why the first equality holds? (why is the L1 norm equal to sup over functions that satisfy |f| <=1 ?)

Answer (score 3):

(This is actually more of a comment, but I do not have that privilege. Since it may be useful, I post it as an answer. If someone can make this a comment, please do so.)

Section IV of the paper [Total Variation Distance and the Distribution of Relative Information](http://ita.ucsd.edu/workshop/14/files/paper/paper_374.pdf) states some lower bounds on total variation in terms of KL divergence, which may be helpful as KL divergence of normal variables has a [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#KL_divergence_for_the_normal_distributions).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another comment. I'm assuming the gaussians are mean 0. If you pick some linear combination of the gaussians, you get in each of cases 1 and 2 a mean 0 gaussian with a variance depending on the covariance matrix entries. A lower bound on the variation distance between these univariate gaussians is a lower bound on the variation distance between the multivariate gaussians. This doesn't seem too tough. Is it the approach that was problematic?

Comment: I certainly should have made that observation... I don't see how to do this nicely even in the case of 2 dimensional Gaussians, but upon consideration it does seem like that should be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose entry $i,j$ differs by $\delta$. For one of $X_i$, or $X_j$, or $X_i+X_j$, the variance differs by at least $\delta/2$ under the two measures, which brings the problem to the 1 dimensional case, which is easy.